# What is the distribution of genotypes of AB0 blood types given the phenotype

Tags: bayesian, genetics

Let's assume we only have the distribution of the phenotypes for a given population.

Let's take Hungary as an example. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type_distribution_by_country)

- $P(0) = 36\%$
- $P(A)=43\%$
- $P(B)=16\%$
- $P(AB)=5\%$

Let's assume that the [Hardy–Weinberg_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle) can be applied, so we can estimate the allele frequencies using [the formulas in this CrossValidated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259352/inferring-alleles-distribution-from-the-blood-types-distribution):

- $o = \sqrt{0.36} = 0.6$
- $a = \sqrt{0.36+0.43} - \sqrt{0.36} = 0.2888$
- $b = 0.1112$

If I know that my blood type is eg. B can I state the the probability that my genotype is BB is given $P(bb|B) = \frac{P(\text{geno=bb and pheno=B})}{P(geno=B)} = \frac{P(geno=bb)}{P(geno=B)} = \frac{0.1112^2}{0.16} = 0.0772$

How should I incorporate additional information, eg. my parent's blood type?